# How do you style <ul hidden></ul> elements without styling all lists?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using a plugin that displays an autocomplete list in a form "dynamically."

I'd like to style the list but can't figure out which element it is or how to target it.

```
<div class="awesomplete">
<input id="omnibar" class="idx-omnibar-input" type="text" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list">
<ul hidden=""></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `input#omnibar + ul {}` ?

Comment: That was very close to the answer I found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the responses.   I was able to solve this by simply selected the div above it and adding li and using !important.

In this case all I wanted to do was style the words in the autocomplete section.

For reference my page was

```
<div id="shortcode_container">
  <div class="awesomplete">
<input id="omnibar" class="idx-omnibar-input" type="text" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off" aria-autocomplete="list">
<ul hidden=""></ul>
</div>

 #shortcode_container {
   color: #ffffff !important;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ul[hidden]` to select the ul elements with that attribute.

```css
ul[hidden] {
display: none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Visible</li>
</ul>
<ul hidden>
  <li>Hidden</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was able to do a few things with this but ultimately I could control things like font color like I liked.  Definitely learned from your response though!

Answer (score 0):

you can use "display" from css and change for display:none or display:block (hidden & visible)

display:none (hidden)
display:block (visible)